# Is data from past dates on the YouTube Analytics API guaranteed not to change?

Tags: youtube-api

Can Google guarantee that data pulled from YouTube Analytics API for any arbitrary date (e.g. March 20th, 2013) will not change in future? For example we pull all kind of reports for March 20th, 2013 today and tomorrow - is it possible to see difference in numbers?

If changes are possible - how frequent such changes could be (all time, once per month, once per year) and how big are they (numbers can get change significantly by 100%-1000%, numbers can get change slightlty by 1%-2%)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such guarantee made, and we can't offer the level of detail you're asking about regarding potential variations.

The YouTube Analytics API uses the same backend data source that the [web interface](http://youtube.com/analytics) uses. In general, [help material](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1714323) that covers questions about data from the web interface also applies to data from the API.